# In Mail Exchange invitation emails get deleted

Tags: mail.app, ical

I use Apple Mail.
I have several email accounts, one of them an MS Exchange Account.

When I receive a meeting invitation in my Exchange Account and "Accept" the invitation, the original email get's deleted.

It only does this on an Exchange Account.

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Deleted or moved to ???

Comment: Sometimes moved to trash sometime deleted.

Comment: That would be normal if you reacted to the invite accepting or denying so the invite is no longer needed

Comment: I vaguely recall this happening in Outlook (years ago). There was a setting in Outlook that changed that behavior, but sorry - no idea what that might be in Apple Mail.